# Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get this error when registering a user:

> (node:13225) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal
>   arguments: undefined, string
>       at Object.bcrypt.hashSync (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:189:19)
>       at module.exports.register (/home/admin/Desktop/project/controllers/auth.js:26:30) (node:13225)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch().(rejection id: 1)

controller:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const db = require('../config/db.config.js')
const User = db.user
const errorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler')

module.exports.register = async function(req, res) {
    const candidate = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: req.body.username
        }
    })

    if (candidate) {
        res.status(409).json({
            message: 'This login is already taken. Try another.'
        })
    } else {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        const password = req.body.password
        const user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            roles: req.body.roles,
            photoSrc: req.file ? req.file.path: '',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        })
        try {
            await user.save()
            res.status(201).json(user)
        } catch(e) {
            errorHandler(res, e)
        }
    }
}
```

models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('users', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        roles: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        photoSrc: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
            default: ''
        }
    });

    return User;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply `await` to your `salt` and `password` assignments too.

Like this,

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const password = await req.body.password;
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect.

Comment: This answer is indeed incorrect. Await without promise will not do anything, there should be no error because of `await` here but there is no reason to add it and it's not related to issue in question in any way. You would need to await for similar function: `bcrypt.genSalt` but this is sync version of it.

Answer (score 3):

This happened with me when I was verifying my registration form, I was searching for the fix but didn't get a proper solution.

**How I fixed it**
Later I realised that I have not passed the required fields before sending post request. [Before Sending **Post request** through **Postman** make sure You have passed **key and value** in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jigzk.png)

Click on Above link to see example.

Comment: This was the best answer for me

Answer (score 2):

For every async operation, we have to await

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the "OTP" field in Schema

Old:

```
Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    requird: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    index: { expires: 300 },
    // after 5 mins it get's deleted
  },
},
{ timestamps: true })
```

New:

```
Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    requird: true,
  },
  otp: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    index: { expires: 300 },
    // after 5 mins it get's deleted
  },
},
{ timestamps: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

working for me like this way, instead of cb, you can use async-await

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
  bcrypt.hash("password", salt, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
  });
});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error using lambda function, but the problem with me was parsing the req body so i had to

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body) // in case of lambda function
```

hope this helps someone.