# Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string at Object.bcrypt.hashSync in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am making an E-Commerce Website using MEAN Stack and Im facing problems with bcrypt. Im not able to create a new user.

Backend - users.js:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
        phone: req.body.phone,
        isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
        street: req.body.street,
        apartment: req.body.apartment,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        city: req.body.city,
        country: req.body.country
    });
    user = await user.save();

    if (!user) return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!');

    res.send(user);
});
```

users-form.component.html:

```
<div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input formControlName="password" id="password" type="password" pInputText />
              <small *ngIf="userForm.password.invalid && isSubmitted" class="p-error"
                >Password is required</small
              >
</div>
```

users-form.component.ts

```
private _addUser(user: User) {
    this.usersService.createUser(user).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Success',
          detail: `User ${user.name} is created!`
        });
        timer(2000)
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => {
            this.location.back();
          });
      },
      () => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'error',
          summary: 'Error',
          detail: 'User is not created!'
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Please help me solve this

Comment: Are you sure that your req.body.password exists and is not undefined ?

Comment: It seems to be defined. Tested witha sample postman POST request and it worked

Comment: Please, take a look at this. Hope it can help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982858/illegal-arguments-undefined-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onSubmit() method didnt have password field previously. Ricardo Machado was right about password not existing. I checked it in the backend, but failed to notice it in angular frontend.

```
onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const user: User = {
      id: this.currentUserId,
      name: this.userForm.name.value,
      password: this.userForm.password.value,
      email: this.userForm.email.value,
      phone: this.userForm.phone.value,
      isAdmin: this.userForm.isAdmin.value,
      street: this.userForm.street.value,
      apartment: this.userForm.apartment.value,
      zip: this.userForm.zip.value,
      city: this.userForm.city.value,
      country: this.userForm.country.value
    };
    if (this.editmode) {
      this._updateUser(user);
    } else {
      this._addUser(user);
    }
  }
```